Can I find the value of a cell B49 that changes value according to the value of the cell F2 ( in Google sheet)

Let in a google sheet all cell changes value according to F2 cell whose value can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11. Now write a formula to find the value of B49 cell when F2=1. The formula should work on another sheet also.
F2 and B49 is in a sheet named 'SchoolWiseList'. I am going to use the funcion in a cell of a sheet named 'ContactPerson'.
If it is possible then please find the sum of all values of B49 when F2=1 to 11.
B49 also changes when F2 changes and it already has function assigned to it.
B49 has the function =MAX(A5:A48)
A5,A6,..A48 has function like =IF(COUNTA($B5:$E5)>0, IFERROR(INDEX($A$4:$A4, MATCH(1, --($B$4:$B4=$B5)*--($D$4:$D4=$D5), 0)), IFERROR(MAX($A$4:$A4), 0)+1), "")
I just want to get the values of B49 when F2 changes it value.
More Explanation:
This table is the details of competitors in a school event. F2 represents the school no. C2 represents the school name. A column represent the serial number of the competitors. B,C,D,E columns represent the details of the competitors. So when F2 changes C2 changes i.e. school name changes and all fields changes accordingly. That is how A column changes and the value of B49 changes. I want to get the total no of competitors for a particular school. Do you need more explanation? Please help me.

You apparently want to increment cell F2 and find what values cell B49 takes during iteration. That can be done, but it's not really how spreadsheets work. It would probably make sense to redesign the spreadsheet so that you can put the series 1..11 in cells F2:F12 and get the corresponding results in cells B49:B59.

Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

=IF(F2=1, B49)?

B49 also changes when F2 changes The formula included in the question do not show a relationship between F2 and B49. Would you please explain how F2 affects the value of B49.

This table is the details of competitors in a school event. F2 represents the school no. C2 represents the school name. A column represent the serial number of the competitors. B,C,D,E columns represent the details of the competitors. So when F2 changes C2 changes i.e. school name changes and all fields changes accordingly. That is how A column changes and the value of B49 changes. I want to get the total no of competitors for a particular school. Do you need more explanation?

Please [edit] the question and add all relevant details there. Sharing images is not helpful. Add a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet.

I have added this function to the apps script and named it total.gs
function recordB49Values() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SchoolWiseList');
  const resultSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Total1');

  const originalF2Value = sheet.getRange('F2').getValue();

  for (let i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('F2').setValue(i);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    
    const B49Value = sheet.getRange('B49').getValue();
    
    resultSheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(i);
    resultSheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(B49Value);
  }

  sheet.getRange('F2').setValue(originalF2Value);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

Then I have added a sheet named Total1. In the Total1 sheet,I set up the headers:
Cell A1: School Number
Cell B1: Total Competitors
Then I run the function recordB49Values from the apps script.

Looks good. If this answers the question you asked, consider marking the answer accepted.
